# Edit Form (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, edit

I am using same form for Create and Edit i have a Folder field and i want to set its value Inbox by default however if a user want to replace it with own folder he /she can replace

```
<input type="text" name="folder" value="INBOX {{isset($mbl->folder) ? $mbl->folder : '' }}" class="form-control" />
```

when i go on edit it shown **INBOX INBOX

I want that Default value should not be show in Edit form it just show the name from Folder remember that i can't remove **value="INBOX"** because i need it i am using it as default value and i am using same form for Create and Edit
Thanks For Help

Comment: try this: ` value="{{isset($mbl->folder) ? $mbl->folder : 'INBOX' }}"`

Comment: simply write value="{{ $mbl->folder or "INBOX"}}"

Comment: Thanks Its working @Rimon Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to pass default value as

```
<input type="text" name="folder" value="{{isset($mbl->folder) ? $mbl->folder : 'INBOX' }}" class="form-control" />
```

Try This hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Simply use it as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="folder" value="{{$mbl->folder or 'INBOX' }}" class="form-control" />
```

More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data).